# Sequelize says instanceMethod is not defined

Tags: mysql, node.js, oop, express, sequelize.js

I'm using sequelize to connect to a mysql db for development. I have a model called Dealer:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var Dealer = sequelize.define('Dealer', {
    id:         { allowNull: false, autoIncrement: true,
                  primaryKey: true, type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED },
    ...
    created_at: { allowNull: false, type: DataTypes.DATE },
    updated_at: { allowNull: false, type: DataTypes.DATE }
  },
  {underscored: true},
  {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        Dealer.hasMany(models.Job);
      }
    },
    instanceMethods: {
      getAllClientData: function(){
        leads = [];
        ...
        return leads;
      },
    }
  });
  return Dealer;
};
```

When I try to call the instance method on an object returned by a sequelize query in my dealerController.js file:

```
dealer.getAllClientData()
```

I get the error:

```
Unhandled rejection TypeError: dealer.getAllClientData is not a function
```

When i print the returned JSON to the console it reads as such:

```
{ dataValues: 
    { id: 1,
      ....
    }
  ...
  '$modelOptions': 
    { timestamps: true,
      instanceMethods: {},
      classMethods: {},
      validate: {},
      freezeTableName: false,
      underscored: true,
      underscoredAll: false,
      paranoid: false,
      rejectOnEmpty: false,
      whereCollection: { id: '1' },
      schema: null,
      schemaDelimiter: '',
      defaultScope: {},
      scopes: [],
      hooks: {},
      indexes: [],
      name: { plural: 'Dealers', singular: 'Dealer' },
      omitNul: false,
      ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Obviously my instanceMethod is not defined, and according to the [sequelize docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations/#one-to-many-associations) I should have getters and setters available too.

I don't understand what step i'm missing here as I've read through much of the sequelize docs and even used their cli to generate the models and migrations.

Any thoughts?

## Edit:

Here is what is output to log for dealer.**prototype**

```
{ _customGetters: {},
  _customSetters: {},
  validators: {},
  _hasCustomGetters: 0,
  _hasCustomSetters: 0,
  rawAttributes: 
   { id: 
      { allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: [Object],
        Model: Dealer,
        fieldName: 'id',
        _modelAttribute: true,
        field: 'id' },
        ///Other Attributes
  },
  _isAttribute: { [Function] cache: MapCache { __data__: [Object] } },
  Model: Dealer,
  $Model': Dealer }
```

Comment: First look seems okay. How are you getting the `dealer` instance?

Comment: FWIW, on my instances, `instanceMethods` is empty as well (but `classMethods` isn't), but they are still available to call. Try logging `dealer.__proto__`.

Comment: @robertklep like so, `models.Dealer.findById(id)`

Comment: @robertklep i edited the post to include the log for dealer.__proto__

Comment: The _only_ thing that I see at this point is that it looks like you're passing `id` as a string to the query, but its data type is an (unsigned) integer. I doubt that that will cause this problem, but other than that, I don't see anything suspicious.

Comment: @robertklep I figured it out. I didn't define my model properly. I have to apologize because i omitted a piece from my model definition in the post because i thought it was unnecessary and it turned out to be the actual issue. Check how i defined the model above, on the line where i call the `underscored` option, I'm sure you'll see the issue.

Comment: Haha whoops :) Well, good to hear that you solved it in the end!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the docs a little further and looking at some other model definitions I discovered that the issue was I had defined my model incorrectly.

In my definition above you'll notice I wrapped the `underscored: true` option in brackets, followed by my classMethods and instanceMethods wrapped in another set of brackets.

This is incorrect. The proper way to define a sequelize model is with two sets of brackets, the first containing your model attributes and the second containing all other options, including methods.

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var Dealer = sequelize.define('Dealer', {
    id:         { allowNull: false, autoIncrement: true,
                  primaryKey: true, type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED },
    ...
    created_at: { allowNull: false, type: DataTypes.DATE },
    updated_at: { allowNull: false, type: DataTypes.DATE }
  },
  {
    underscored: true,
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        Dealer.hasMany(models.Job);
      }
    },
    instanceMethods: {
      getAllClientData: function(){
        leads = [];
        ...
        return leads;
      },
    }
  });
  return Dealer;
};
```